# How to catch nested exceptions caused by http request and timeout?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to attach a timeout to a POST request. When the request hangs, the timeout throws an exception that's caught by the catch cause. However, few more seconds later, another exception is thrown by send() method with the actual issue. https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/BaseRequest/send.html (rethrow)

How can I catch the second nested exception? The control flow has already exited the try-catch block.

```
final request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri);
try {
  final response = await request.send().timeout(Duration(seconds: 2))
} on TimeoutException {
  logger.d("Request failed by timing out!"); // Catches 2 seconds timeout reliably.
} catch (e) {
  logger.d('An error occurred: $e');
}
```

Comment: Did you try to increase timeout? You wrote " few more seconds later", it looks like 2 sec is not enough to process a request

Comment: And what is 2nd exception exactly?

Comment: Can you attach a reproducible sample?

Comment: I run the backend using FastAPI. It only reliably fails by not having google cloud credentials for login for some of the services so it's hard to post a complete example.

Using just 
```
response = await request.send()
```

i was able to catch this error after 5-10 seconds
```
Operation timed out
```

But with 
```
response = await request.send().timeout(Duration(seconds: 2))
```
I was able to catch `TimeoutException`. But after a few seconds the original exception breaks the program
```
_ClientSocketException (Operation timed out)
```